# Git pull reverts commits, maybe workflow

Tags: git, version-control

One team team in the company i work is having troubles with git.

- 1 - Say dev1 ads a line to file.txt commits and pushes.
- 2 - Meanwhile dev2 works on the same file, but do not touches the same lines.
- 3 - Dev2 commits, pulls and pushes.
- 4 - When dev1 pulls the line in step 1 is somehow missing. It was removed. (Sometimes dev1 sees an error message saying that the editor could not be opened for editing the merge commit message, as explained in more details bellow)

I don't think this is a git bug or something, since I have never had that kind of problem. I really think the problem is in the workflow. I thought that it could be that file.txt was no refreshed by sublime editor after dev2 pulled, but that is no the cause.

Anyone had a similar problem?

### Edit:

My git version is 1.7.9.5
dev1 is 1.7.12.4
dev2 is 1.7.10.4

Dev1 reports some pull merges code but says it failed since the editor could not be opened. I never heard of editing commit message after pulling and that lead me to [this post](http://git-blame.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/anticipating-git-1710.html), which explaines that versopm 1.7.10+ opens editor for providing a merge message after pulling.
Could that cause problems?

#### Edit 2

Also, dev1 git config is

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
   url = url
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path =
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
trustExitCode = true
```

#### Edit 3

The commit hashes are all hashes related to the dev1 pull that caused revealed the problem.
The first column is the number of line

```
git ld | nl | grep -e 9b95d03 -e 53d397d -e d6b221c -e fd73722 -e d4ae4c1 -e 2e4fe3b -e 63ac034 -e 7b20cd0 -e 81b6bf4 -e 087583c

 4  9b95d03 | 4 hours ago | Merge branch 'master' of git:repo | [dev1] ######## pulls and bazinga! Line gone.
 5  53d397d | 4 hours ago | fake msg | [dev1]
 8  d6b221c | 5 hours ago | Merge branch 'master' of git:repo | [dev2]
 9  fd73722 | 5 hours ago | fake msg | [dev1]
10  d4ae4c1 | 5 hours ago | fake msg | [dev2]  ######### line removed. [dev2] sweares he wasn't working near that feature 
16  2e4fe3b | 18 hours ago | Merge branch 'master' of git:repo | [dev2]
17  63ac034 | 18 hours ago | Merge branch 'master' of git:repo | [dev2]
18  7b20cd0 | 18 hours ago | add shadow | [dev1]
19  81b6bf4 | 18 hours ago | ajustes | [dev2]
20  087583c | 19 hours ago | add widget blog | [dev1] ######## line added
```

#### Edit 4

```
# git log --graph --ancestry-path 087583c..9b95d03 -- assets/styles/site.css

*   commit 9b95d03ccbfbcc21269c703f07e30c4b03517d00
|\  Merge: fd73722 d6b221c
| | Author: Dev1
| | Date:   Wed Jun 26 11:19:46 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of git:repo
| |     
| *   commit d6b221c96c227f7577f8322d77fe56537f1a86df
| |\  Merge: d4ae4c1 fd73722
| |/  Author: Dev2
|/|   Date:   Wed Jun 26 09:53:07 2013 -0300
| |   
| |       Merge branch 'master' of git:repo
| |   
| * commit d4ae4c1c21ae1b904cf6609331459c0eca7bb774
| | Author: Dev2
| | Date:   Wed Jun 26 09:51:04 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     acabamentos resp
| |   
* | commit fd73722b1c5a9045e5de2e5fb5fc50334f66b75a
| | Author: Dev1
| | Date:   Wed Jun 26 09:51:25 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     fix menu sabotado
| |   
* | commit 787b77d2e513c9358be0d077ad37860d244c1373
| | Author: Dev1
| | Date:   Wed Jun 26 09:39:32 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     devolucao de código sabotado
| |   
* | commit cfa4b113d668a12ee784a13dc488887c7a7a59c5
| | Author: Dev1
| | Date:   Tue Jun 25 21:01:45 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     fix menus
| |   
* | commit 8037155ae0ae0089bc589a4fc7071fba825546c5
| | Author: Dev1
| | Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:45:41 2013 -0300
| | 
| |     acabamentos fix
| |     
* |   commit 64459bb5dc0284ea103c739464798f0da0e704a9
|\ \  Merge: af2f520 2e4fe3b
| |/  Author: Dev1
| |   Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:38:24 2013 -0300
| |   
| |       Merge branch 'master' of git:repo
| |     
| *   commit 2e4fe3b5a8f7efe2d6f3b15403e964134c888c7b
| |\  Merge: 63ac034 7b20cd0
| | | Author: Dev2
| | | Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:31:51 2013 -0300
| | | 
| | |     Merge branch 'master' of git:repo
| | |    
| * | commit 63ac0340faabc9defe4a45f65aeccaf3e5aba8b9
|  /  Merge: 81b6bf4 087583c
| |   Author: Dev2
| |   Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:30:57 2013 -0300
| |   
| |       Merge branch 'master' of git:repo
| |   
* | commit af2f5200269e2f3fa22ec911a14149357a8e3810
|/  Author: Dev1
|   Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:38:18 2013 -0300
|   
|       fix
|  
* commit 7b20cd0b44fddc6b594546f6d75049d1c4522119
  Author: Dev1
  Date:   Tue Jun 25 20:30:54 2013 -0300
  
      add shadow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe it just can't happen.

It can happen if step 3 is really:

- Dev2 commits and pushes
- gets message that push failed with long text somewhere mentioning 'force'
- dev2 uses push -f

And what happens is exactly as was told in the long unread portion of the text -- dev1's commit is sent to oblivion.

But that must be obvious from the history, if there was alcually a pull, you must see a "bus-stop" and both commits.

If you see it and the content is really gone, you must see the revert happening in the merge commit.  It may happen as a text-editor artifact, file was changed, the editor asked tyo reload, told NO, then eventually saves the old version.

If the merge went auto without conflicts it's still unclear how it managed in the commit, but enough enigmas for one speculative run. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. That does not seem to be the senario though. I edited the question providing more details.

Comment: @Marcelo: I don't see how commit message popup could be relevant. Let's start exploring the state: does the history have Dev1's commit? And if it does, which commit above it makes it reverted?

Comment: @Marcelo: so at 53d397d the line is there, at 9b95d03 it is missing, both commits commits made by dev1, and no commits between?

Comment: No. At commit 53d397d the line is not there. But commits from from 53d397d to fd73722 appeared in dev1 history after the last time dev1 pulled

Comment: @Marcelo: getting closer, please paste result of `git log --graph --ancestry-path 087583c..9b95d03 path/yourfile.xxx` (with the bad file) and indicate each intermediate commit as having the line or not (I assume the first have it and last not)

Comment: Although we could not reproduce the error, it seems that file wasn't being reloaded after pulling. I asked the devs to close their editors before pulling and the problems seem to have stoped. Thank you @Balog Pal for your help

Answer (score 0):

(reflecting on edits)

The last info is useful, however indication of where the miss start really would have helped. 
Let me pick out the likely points:

commit 2e4fe3b5 D2
commit 64459bb  D1
commit d6b221c  D2
commit 9b95d03  D1

Edit3 seem to indicate that at d6b221c the change is still there. If so, you must see the reverting effect in diff  d6b221c..9b95d03 and Dev1 is to "blame". (otherwise provide the missing info)

In cases like that I usually test the tools redoing the merge (or whatever operation).
If 9b95d03 is confirmed, then it means creating a temp branch on both of its parent and ask a merge, then see what happens.

As a more general note, you guys managed to make an incredible mess of the history in a single day. I seriously suggest you switch tactics. I would even if no problematic merge was encountered.

Your history should look completely linear. Just stop dong `git pull`, and switch to `git pull --rebase` and the primary way of work. At least when there are no conflicts. Especially if you normally push patches right as they are done. (5 merges in 12 hours quite indicates that)

Comment: I hadn't known --rebase options til yesterday. This will be the way from now on. We'll ignore the errors that occurred til now and see if we can find out what happened. Case we find the answer I'll post here, otherwise I'll check your answer as the correct one. Again, thank you very much @balog Pal

Comment: something came to mind. Dev1 and dev2 worked at the same time. Thats why so many merges in that time. Isn't that correct?

Comment: working at same time is completely natural with git (doing either merge or rebase), the implementation resolves technical race conditions and pass logical ones to the human users